# what should I use to hit a remote url with parameters and use the response in code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

I am developing an application in PHP where I need to hit a remote URL with few parameters which will be returning me some response and I need to use the response in my code, now I am not able to understand whether I should use **Ajax requests** or **PHP curl request**?

what will be the faster and efficient way of doing it?

what will be the differences in the requests generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question lacks context, you should probably use php (cURL is one option) and not ajax / javascript:

- When you use ajax, the information will end up in the visitors browser, not your php application so you would need to make an additional request to your own application to get it there.
- You could run into cross-domain problems when you use javascript / ajax to make a request to a remote url.

If you need the information in your php application, the most efficient is to make the request directly from php.